# Salesforce Marketing cloud - Object - Which attribute can be queried in soap API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am trying to know which folder a particular Job (Send) is present in tracking.

In Send object , we have

```
<Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CategoryID</Properties>
```

Email definition. On Definition i have category id . I am trying to get the category id of email definition associated to sent

However i am getting error

```
<OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) EmailSendDefinition.CategoryID do not match with the fields of Send retrieve</OverallStatus>
```

To know which attribute i can query i did a describe on sent objects. In response for each attribute, i get lots of metadata . for example:

```
{
                    "Name": "CategoryID",
                    "DataType": "Int32",
                    "ValueType": "xsdstring",
                    "PropertyType": "string",
                    "IsCreatable": false,
                    "IsUpdatable": true,
                    "IsRetrievable": true,
                    "IsQueryable": false,
                    "IsFilterable": false,
                    "IsPartnerProperty": false,
                    "IsAccountProperty": false,
                    "PartnerMap": null,
                    "AttributeMaps": null,
                    "Markups": null,
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "Label": null,
                    "Description": null,
                    "DefaultValue": null,
                    "MinLength": 0,
                    "MaxLength": 0,
                    "MinValue": null,
                    "MaxValue": null,
                    "IsRequired": false,
                    "IsViewable": false,
                    "IsEditable": false,
                    "IsNillable": false,
                    "IsRestrictedPicklist": false,
                    "PicklistItems": null,
                    "IsSendTime": false,
                    "DisplayOrder": 0,
                    "References": null,
                    "RelationshipName": null,
                    "Status": null,
                    "IsContextSpecific": false,
                    "Client": null,
                    "PartnerKey": null,
                    "PartnerProperties": null,
                    "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                    "ModifiedDate": null,
                    "ID": 0,
                    "ObjectID": null,
                    "CustomerKey": null,
                    "Owner": null,
                    "CorrelationID": null,
                    "ObjectState": null,
                    "IsPlatformObject": false
                },
```

Which tag on this attribute denote that a particular attribute is query able in soap api?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `"IsRetrievable": true` part when doing Describe method. If it is "true" then you can retrieve a value for the specified property.

Unfortunately, you cannot find Jobs by "CategoryID" on the Tracking page.

What you can do:

1. Retrieve [EmailSendDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/emailsenddefinition.html) and its "CategoryID"
2. Map it with [Send](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html) object and retrieve aggregate data based on a JobID.

Example of EmailSendDefinitionobject retrieval with WSProxy -

```js
<script language = "javascript" runat = "server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

try {

   var cols   = ["Name", "CategoryID"];
   var filter = {Property: "Name", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "xxxxxxx"};   
   var result = prox.retrieve("EmailSendDefinition", cols, filter);
   
   Write(Stringify(result));

} catch(e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```